# Add path to Current AppDomain

Tags: appdomain, appdomainsetup

I have two completely different directories. Directory 1 contains my application and Directory 2 having few assemblies. During run-time when application launches, I will load the assemblies. By default, the executing Assembly's AppDomain will discover the assemblies in Directory 1 (application folder) or GAC. If the file is not there, we will get the error. But I have to extend the AppDomain's search directory to search in Directory 2 also. That is, AppDomain will search Directory1 (local bin), then GAC, then other defaults at last search in Directory 2.

I have tried :
1. By setting PrivateBinPath, but it is restricted only within ApplicationBaseDirectory. 
2. By AssemblyResolve, but it is not directly referenced. The AssemblyResolve code never hits also.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `AssemblyResolve` event is generally the correct way. If it is never hit, it is probably bound to too late. For instance, when the CLR encounters a method, it will compile it completely, resolving all its references. If such resolution fails, it will fail always. If you bind the `AssemblyResolve` event *after* any or all assemblies failed binding, the event will never hit.

To resolve this, make sure that the `AssemblyResolve` event is bound as early as possible. In an executable this is easy enough (first thing in the entry point of your application, or any `cctor` of a type you use there). In a library this can be harder, best practice approach is to use the module initializer, which is run whenever a module is loaded (most assemblies contain one module).

Since the module initializer cannot be set by C# or any other .NET language I know of, you have to resort to method weaving. I personally like Fody and as it turns out, there's a predefined Fody package called [Fody Module Init](https://github.com/Fody/ModuleInit) for exactly this thing.

Just place, somewhere publicly in your library, the following code:

```
public static class ModuleInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        // bind to the CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve event
    }
}
```

Fody also works with other languages (you don't specify which you use), but then you'll have to create the static `ModuleInitializer` class by hand.

Using this approach, you can be certain that the `AssemblyResolve` event *will* be called for any assembly that CLR's Fusion cannot find by itself.